# how to delete margin-top: 32px !important from twenty twelve

Tags: wordpress, themes, margin

I want to remove the margin-top property from twenty twelve theme. This is the default theme provided by wordpress. The sample of the code what I found with the help of firebug.

```
html{
     margin-top: 32px !important;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the CSS files and removing the statements?

Comment: Yes I have. but no luck this is because I have not found this chunk of code within the style.css

Answer (score 45):

```
function remove_admin_login_header() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
```

Comment: You, sir, get a like!

Comment: Alternatively, one can just log out (which your answer got me there - thanks!)

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I looked through the WP source and found the following: `add_theme_support( 'admin-bar', array( 'callback' => '__return_false' ) );`

Comment: Cool, rather call it remove_admin_login_margin so you prevent confusion - the header stays there :)

Answer (score 18):

A better way to do this is to add theme support for the admin bar with a callback of "return false", then Wordpress wont ever trigger the `_admin_bar_bump_cb` action which is responsible for adding in the `margin-top:32px`.

```
add_theme_support( 'admin-bar', array( 'callback' => '__return_false' ) );
```

Answer (score 12):

Add the following function to your functions.php file

```
function my_function_admin_bar(){ return false; }
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

Comment: On the last version of Worpress 5.0.3, this solution works perfectly, the other ones or all i found around are not doing anything or even broken the site! Cheers

Comment: You can make this even shorter/simpler by using [the WordPress core utility callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_false/) `__return_false`, like this:

`add_filter(  'show_admin_bar' , '__return_false' );`

Answer (score 3):

Go to the functions file inside your theme folder:

functions.php

```
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');

function remove_admin_login_header() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter like this:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are logged in in your wordpress account and that 32px space corresponds to the black menu line that is on the top of your page, which doesn't appear but leaves the space for it . Log out and refresh the page and see if it continues or open the website in an other browser.

Answer (score 0):

in the style.css around line #1645 is body .site { which has padding top & bottom:

```
body .site {
    padding: 0 40px;
    padding: 0 2.857142857rem;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-top: 3.428571429rem;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 3.428571429rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it....

html.k-webkit.k-webkit78 { margin-top: 0 !important; }

Answer (score 0):

In dashboard in sidebar go to Users -> Profile,then in profile uncheck "Show Toolbar when viewing site".Update changes and margin-top will disapear.
That's where the margin comes from.

Answer (score -2):

Remove margin from h1 - h6 elements. WP have default margins and that is why you see 32px !Important in inline HTML code.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue. I got rid of

```
wp_head();
```

in the header template and problem solved.

Comment: Removing `wp_head()` in a WordPress theme is a bad idea. WordPress itself as well as many plugins depend on this function to insert styles, scripts and other things.

Answer (score -4):

You can specify an identifier for the html tag in the template and set it to margin-top: 0! important;

```
#html {margin-top: 0 !important;}
```