# How to remove white margin/space on top of my Landing Page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm having the following problem:

I've created a landing page with a wordpress plugin from my website (As building it with the plugin I have is SO EASY!) then copied the source html code and pasted it into the wanted wordpress site, into a blank page.

The problem is that now wordpress is creating a weird margin (white space) on top making the landing page appear further down.

**Can I copy source html code and past into a Wordpress page and avoid white margin on top ?**

*Everything looks like working fine when I copy and paste then HTML code, besides this annoying top margin that I really don't understand where is coming from...*

Comment: Please show some code or preferably a live URL.

Comment: Can you show us your landing page code please?

Comment: Answering a question without seeing the code is similar to chiromancy, but I guess you're simply copying _all_ the code into whatever, along with `html`, `head` and `body` tags.

Comment: There's another post with the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491619/how-to-delete-margin-top-32px-important-from-twenty-twelve

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your CSS page
2. put

   *{margin:0px;
   padding:0px}

It will remove your white margin and padding*

Comment: don't make margin and padding 0 on everything element (*)

Comment: Hey guys, Thank you for your reply. I've tried doing so, unfortunately it won't work. Any other suggestion? Is only related to certain pages, not the entire website. Is there any way I can adjust that maybe adding some code into the html? If yes, where exactly should I put The code? THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU